# laravel fatal error for TestCase not found

Tags: php, laravel

```
http://localhost/laravel/app/tests/ExampleTest.php
```

if i run laravel it shows the following error

Fatal error: Class 'TestCase' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\tests\ExampleTest.php on line 3 , any idea

Comment: I don't believe tests are meant to be ran that way. You are supposed to use PHPUnit through the command line.

Answer (score 18):

Run following command in your project's root directory

```
phpunit app/tests/
```

**Update:**

You can also run with the following command if phpunit is not installed on your machine. Which is also better to avoid version differences between team mates.

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

[image]

Comment: @ConnorLeech propably phpunit is not installed on your machine. You can try to run like this "vendor/bin/phpunit"

Answer (score 14):

Check if your `tests` directory is listed on the `classmap` property of your `composer.json` file.

If not add it and run `composer dump-autoload`.

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests",
        "database/"
    ]
},
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of headache! I added tests to my classmap and then ran a composer dump. Fixed my problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue with PHPUnit, he would output always the same message : `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Tests\TestCase' not found ...` and indeed I think he had troubles to find that class so what you need to do is transform one line :

From this :

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class AnotherTest extends TestCase {
    public function testExample() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

To this :

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class AnotherTest extends TestCase {
    public function testExample() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

> Notice the first line in use and you should do this if there's any other files in the same case

Comment: The issue here is that you're including the PHPUnit TestCase, and not the laravel one, so you're going to miss out on laravel specific features

Answer (score 6):

In my case, i noticed that my root folder not contained the phpunit.xml file.

Solve it including the following code in phpunit.xml at the root folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./app/tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 5):

You haven't really given much information to go on here, but the specific problem is probably that you don't have an autoloader (thus the `TestCase` class that PHP is expecting isn't actually loaded. The underlying problem in turn is likely that you're trying to run `ExampleTest.php` directly on the terminal, whereas instead you must bootstrap a test environment correctly through Laravel and PHPUnit.

You should find a phpunit.xml file in the root of your Laravel install. This file tells PHPUnit how to bootstrap and start executing tests for your application, so you should just be able to run `phpunit` on the command line in the root of your application and it should work.

If that's not the issue, please do provide more detail for people to help with.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue, you should run test from root folder, in your case 'http://localhost/laravel' and in terminal you just need to write phpunit, and test will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error but none worked,

except for this one, this worked for me,

I tried reinstalling and upgrading my phpunit in Laravel 5.4,

1. modify compose.json -> find these line and change the phpunit version

   "require-dev": {
           "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.4"
       },
2. after editing, run on your cmd,

   composer update
3. then run

   composer dump-autoload
4. `php artisan config:clear`
5. `php artisan cache:clear`
6. finally, 
   run `phpunit`

or run specific unit,  `phpunit --filter yourTestCaseClass`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The is caused by an outdated phpunit. If you using a globally installed phpunit, here is a link on how to update it https://stackoverflow.com/a/40701333/3792206  . Or you can explicitly use the phpunit that was installed with the project.

Answer (score 0):

My laravel phpunit was working and then suddenly started giving me this error.  Running composer install again solved it.

Answer (score 0):

After wracking my brains over this for a very late hour, in the end it turned out I was completely missing the `tests/TestCase.php` file, for some mysterious reason. Creating the file with the following content, taken directly from the [Laravel 9 GitHub repo](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/tests/TestCase.php), fixed the issue for me:

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
}
```